# Left Align hyperlink on boostrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.

I have a hyperlink in a row that I like to align similar to how I have my other rows that use

```
    <div class="row" id="remove_detail" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 deskpadd">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">                   
                <label class="control-label" >test</label>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

When I have this it shows as follows:

[image]

I have a hyperlink that I like to replace it with but when I do it, it does not align properly.

```
    <div class="row" id="remove_detail" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 deskpadd">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">                   
               <a class="remove_button pull-left" id="removeAccordion" onclick="RemoveValidationDetail('@i')" style="color:#aaa;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>&nbsp; remove</a>

            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The above shows as shown below

[image]

How can I have this hyperlink properly align left similar to how the label was aligned?

Comment: So we can't actually see what's causing that. Can you create a fiddle or something similar so we can inspect? Have you checked obvious things like padding / margins that could be creating the left gap?

Comment: I have done the same in codepen and it seems to be ok. https://codepen.io/R1112/pen/XWrLXMB . If you can show us your HTML and css that will help us to provide better assistance